# What formats are allowed for Google Analytics virtual pageviews?

Tags: url, google-analytics

Do Google Analytics virtual pageviews have to be urls? Are any other string formats valid, and are the allowable formats documented?

Answer (score 1):

As far as the documentation goes, I am not sure if there is one. In fact if there actually needs to be one as there is just one **STRING** parameter you need to use. And it can be "anything" (for example: *'/downloads/dynamic-form'*) that would supplement a unique URL which cannot due to some technical reason used but would make sense to include as a seperate page-view within Google Analytics report.

Example of use virtual pageviews:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/downloads/dynamic-form']);
```

There is however a lot of use-cases where *Events* would do a better job, as tracking virtual pageviews "will add to your total pageview count" (see the [official GA documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/asyncMigrationExamples?hl=en#VirtualPageviews)). For example downloads, outbound links, buttons etc.

Be careful with using [Events](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide?hl=en) however, as there are some limitations as well and make sure you specify whether it is an interaction or non-interaction event (this has impact on other reports like Bounce Rate and etc.).